# $resource URL Structures

Tags: angularjs, url, service, resources

Having a bit of a problem structuring my urls I want a customer ID passed as a param inside the url but when I use a get request it keeps attaching it as a param at the end.

This is how I want the url to look
**customer/CUSTOMER ID HERE/resource**

But it keeps coming out as
**customer/resource?CUSTOMER ID**

my query url is 
**api/v1/customers/:customerId/resource**

and my service code is this

```
   .factory("MOH", ['$resource', function($resource){
        return $resource(MyAaa.AppConfig.customerResourceEndpoint,{customerId: '@customer_id'}, {
          query:{method: "GET", params:{}, isArray:false}} 
}])
```

Comment: Can you update your question with `MOH.query({...})` method declaration?

Comment: Hey hows things, I just used MOH.get instead and it worked!

Comment: I guess, you specified wrong parameter name before; if you specify like this `MOH.query({ customerId: 'CUST029' });`  it would work.